# How to use jquery to hide elements on mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

In my script tag of my index page I have:

```
if ($(window).width() < 700px){
  $('container').hide();
}
```

In my console I am receiving an

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected input

Comment: just remove the "px" and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly `700 px` is not a valid expression. It would be if it was in quotes to make it a string, but that wouldn't work (as you expect it to) with the `<` operator. As the `width()` method returns an integer just compare it to `700`.

Secondly, `container` is not a valid selector as there is no `<container />` element in HTML. I presume that's supposed to be an `id` or `class` selector and you've missed the `#` or `.` prefix.

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
  $('#container').hide(); // or .container, maybe?
}
```

***However***, if you're trying to make the layout of your page responsive to the width of the display you should not be using JS. Use CSS Media Queries instead:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) { 
  #container {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: The px was the problem, thank you! I am using CSS media queries but I needed this for a toggle function that I use later.